# Nuget Package Compatibility and Upgrades

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

My company has internal components that we deliver via internal NuGet. Now i want to make a Version 5.X of these components which will be breaking a lot from the 4.X versions. 
However now if my colleagues browse for updates, the Nuget browser would recommend these new packages.

What i would prefer: If example 4.6 is installed, it would take the highest 4.X version but not 5.0 or above. Making packages for the 5.X path under completely different names would be annoying when the developer choses to upgrade.

Is there a way to mark nuget packages to do something like that? If that's not clear, tell me and i try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your projects are using `packages.config`, you can use `allowedVersions`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema

There's no way to do this if your project uses PackageReference, but you can upvote () this isse: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9082

Comment: Ah, nice! Thank you for your help!